# React Native Expo App Missing Status Bar in TestFlight

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

After building the standalone iOS native binary using Expo, uploading to Testflight and running it on an iPhone, the status bar looks like there are many elements missing.

What might be the cause of this? How can we fix it? Thanks!

**In iPhone Expo Client:**

Status bar looks normal.

[image]

**In TestFlight:**

Status bar appears to be empty except for the green battery indicator

[image]

**/src/Routes/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { BottomNavigation, BottomNavigationTab, BottomNavigationProps, withStyles } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';


...



class BottomNavigationTabsComponent extends React.Component {
    render() { ... }
}

BottomNavigationTabs = withStyles(BottomNavigationTabsComponent, (theme) => ({
    bottomNavigation: {
        borderTopColor: theme['border-basic-color-2'],
        borderTopWidth: 1
    }
}));

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Foo: FooScreen,
        Bar: BarScree,
    }, {
        initialRouteName: 'Foo',
        tabBarComponent: BottomNavigationTabs,
        tabBarOptions: {
            indicatorStyle: {
                height: 0       // remove indicator
            }
        }
    }
)

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    Login: LoginScreen,
    Baz: BazScreen,
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
})


const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: TabNavigator,
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Auth: AuthStack,
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootNavigator);

export default AppContainer
```

**/src/App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { mapping, light as lightTheme } from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider, Layout } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';

import ApplicationLoader from './ApplicationLoader'
import AppContainer from './Routes';

export class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <ApplicationLoader assets={assets}>
            <ApplicationProvider
            mapping={mapping}
            theme={lightTheme}>
            <AppContainer/>
            </ApplicationProvider>
        </ApplicationLoader>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

**app.json**

```
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "FooBar",
        "slug": "foo-bar",
        "privacy": "public",
        "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
        "platforms": [
            "ios",
            "android",
            "web"
        ],
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#000"
        },
        "updates": {
            "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": [
            "**/*"
        ],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true,
            "bundleIdentifier": "com.foo.bar"
        },
        "android": {
            "package": "com.foo.bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we see the content of `app.json`?

Comment: @Remeus Sure, I have updated the question with `app.json`

Comment: Are you setting the `StatusBar` yourself in the code? Something like: `<StatusBar barStyle="light-content" /> `. Because it looks like the text is written in white for whatever reason.

Comment: Maybe try to explictly set it in `App.js`: `import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content', true);`

Comment: @Remeus Your second solution works! Both Expo client app and Testflight app has a visible status bar content. Did not try your first soution. Thank you!

Comment: @Remeus, you're a lifesaver.  `StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content', true);` worked for me when nothing else would.